# Finding which function was used to assign the variable (Through variable which is assigned)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have one function ***GetControlRectangle(Rectangle MethodRect)*** that accepts the rectangle of the control.

Now I write the code like ***Rectangle rct=dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(1,0,false);*** which finds the location of the cell(1,0) of the ***datagridview1***.

And I pass this ***rct*** to the method ***GetControlRectangle***.

Now how to find through the ***MethodRect***(which is the argument in the method)that which function was used to get this rectangle point like ***GetCellDisplayRectangle()*** or ***GetColumnDisplayRectangle()***. Because I want to know in the method ***GetControlRectangle()*** that this point is for **columnheader** or **cell** and it is for cell then for which cell.

In short, I want to know that which function was used through variable which is assigned like ***Rectangle rct=dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(1,0,false);*** through rct I want to know which function was used to assign this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if **I** understood correctly, he should just modify the `GetControlRectangle(Rectangle MethodRect)` function so that it looks like `GetControlRectangle(Rectangle MethodRect, bool IsHeader)` and then have the calling code do the deciding of "which function was called".

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to convert **rct** into getter/setter pair. In the setter, create a new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace() (just call ToString() method to get a readable representation). It will contain the call stack, in this case, the function that is setting the new value for **rct**.

Something like this (replace exception with more suitable handling):

```
Rectangle _rct=null;
Rectangle rct {
  get { return _rct; }
  set {
    throw new Exception(new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString());
    //_rct=value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail pleaze?

Comment: what does do System.Diagnostics.StackTrace() ?